# regex match all after a string with positive lookbehind and input it behind every selection

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, python-regex

> copyright: hololive hololive_english
> character: mori_calliope takanashi_kiara takanashi_kiara_(phoenix)
> artist: xu_chin-wen
> species:
> meta: web

I want to select every word after eg:`character:` so i can put eg:`character:` behind every selection,

> `character:`mori_calliope `character:`takanashi_kiara `chararcter:`takanashi_kiara_(phoenix)

the closest thing i got is

```
(?<=(\w*):\s*\S*\s.*)(?<=\s)(?=\S)
```

which works properly but it breaks when there is a single entry on eg:`character: something` or when its empty

i would be really thankfull if someone would help

Comment: What is the environment?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew python

Comment: Then you will need PyPi regex module if you want to do it with plain regex. Else, truncate the string up to and including `character:` substring and match the words till end of line (or here  just split with whitespace).

Comment: why is that? i have a `re` module in python. I could just run the regex twice, once to isolate just the words after `character:` and a second time to input the `char:` string behind every word. But i want to do it in one go

Comment: Then `re` won't help.

Comment: so theres no way i can positive lookbehind every word after a specific string?

Comment: No.......................................

Comment: how would i do it in PyPi regex then?, i also updated the post to be a little more specific on what i want to achieve

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/SIDogU/1 or https://regex101.com/r/SIDogU/2

Comment: thank you, but how do i input something behind all those selections? or copy the first string of the line like `character:` or `artist:` to be behind all those? It would be usefull to do that for the whole block of text

Comment: If you mean you need to capture the word and insert before each word, only the lookbehind version will work: find `(?<=(character):\s*\S+\s.*)(?<=\s)(?=\S)` and replace with `$1:` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/SIDogU/3)).

Comment: that works, but how do i ad a flag to replace it till the end of a line? cuz it breaks when there are some empty `something:` elements and it imputs `something:` into the next element like: `something:` \n `something:meta: something:highres`. Also it selects from the second word, not from the first one

Comment: i achieved the result i wanted with `(?<=(\w*):\s*\S*\s.*)(?<=\s)(?=\S)` but it breaks when there is an empty tag like `test:` \n `test:test2: test:tag1 test:tag2` or the `test:` has only one element

Comment: Please update the question with the real problem statement (you are replacing text, and you want to turn X into Y, please clarify this in the question) and add all restrictions.

Comment: i have updated the question, i would be thankfull for help

Comment: So, what is wrong with `character: something` or empty string? What do you expect for both inputs? I think nothing needs to change in these strings.

Comment: plug the regex with the quotes on the top of the post and you will see whats the issue

Comment: i want them to either skip if its empty and if it has a single element, select them. If they have a single one, it skips it

Comment: If you have a `character: something` string, there is nothing to modify. You need to clarify what you are trying to achieve by providing the code you are using, the programming language, and real-life test case.

Comment: the example is on the top of the post and the regex im using is in the post too. and its python since you told me to use PyPi

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew https://regex101.com/r/XYPxqT/1

Comment: I can only guess what you want: https://regex101.com/r/XYPxqT/2 ?

Comment: yes exactly what i wanted to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You should install [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and use

```
regex.sub(r'(?<=(\w+):.*)(?<=\s)(?=\S)', r'\1:', text)
# or
# regex.sub(r'(?<=(\w+:).*)(?<=\s)(?=\S)', r'\1', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XYPxqT/4).
*Details*:

- `(?<=(\w+):.*)` -  a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with any word (captured into Group 1) followed by a `:` char and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
  (?<=\s)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a whitespace char
- `(?=\S)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a non-whitespace char.

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##XY/BasMwEETv@YolF0ttGii9iZp@RK8CoYjFWiKvxGpTO1/vOBR66OnNwMDMtLvmyh/bRnOroiA44XpQXBVGOKba7kJTVge5llroB/9EQJ4K9ew55SgxKYqDuQqFFEuh2hA0XiPHnilcaY/898G0XJFptZ6jKPW9Zr2FlInfFmTPvWEi7M7zjBodLHg5HpoQq/kdeu63i5HBfH2Oxi@v1p1f7NP4vmP033Y4gQz@3e18frJgt@0B):

```py
import regex
text = "copyright: hololive hololive_english\ncharacter: mori_calliope takanashi_kiara takanashi_kiara_(phoenix)\nartist: xu_chin-wen\nspecies:\nmeta: web"
print( regex.sub(r'(?<=(\w+):.*)(?<=\s)(?=\S)', r'\1:', text) )
```

Output:

```
copyright: copyright:hololive copyright:hololive_english
character: character:mori_calliope character:takanashi_kiara character:takanashi_kiara_(phoenix)
artist: artist:xu_chin-wen
species:
meta: meta:web
```